# How to solve JavaScript critical error during debug

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a vb project in VS2015. When I debug, I got the JavaScript critical error. The javascript is called many pages and other pages are no problem.  However if I click view in Browser, there is no error.  I checked the source code and didn't find what cause this issue.Would someone tell me how to get away the error during debug. Thanks in advance.

There is my code to call the javascript:

```
<input name="btnEdit" class="btnWide" id="btnEdit" onclick="openWin('popEdit.aspx?ID=5623','editHearing',600,600); return false;" type="submit" value="Edit">
```

There is the error message during debug:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 100, column 200 in the  http://localhost:5510/Order/popEdit.aspx?ID=5623\n\nSCRIPT1003:Expected’:’
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo somewhere, presumably in `openWin()`. It's either a missing `:` character, or something that's leading the interpreter to think it should see one. You can hunt for the typo on your own, or post your JavaScript into your question and we can help.